ProcessBuilder process thread hangs with larger stdin stream
I'm trying to pass a byte array to stdin when running a process with ProcessBuilder. If I write a small amount like 100000 bytes it works. When writing somewhat more than this the thread hangs. What am I missing here?
This simplified code shows what I'm trying to do
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command("cat");
Process process = builder.start();

OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(stdin);
outputStream.write(data);
outputStream.close();

byte[] out = stdout.readAllBytes();


Take a look here. A 24 year old article. https://www.infoworld.com/article/2157336/when-runtime-exec-won-t.html

Try reading the error stream amd close all streams properly.!

Is that your real problem? I ask as you've just invented a complex way of manipulating stdin

The freeze can occur if writes to stdin are on same threads as consumers of stdout/err.

Many executables, like 'cat', will have limited buffering capacity. They will eventually block while writing to their stdout if it is not being read by the destination (the OS may have additional buffering but limited too).
If such process is also no longer reading from its stdin because it is waiting to write on stdout, then it is the upstread producer (your java class) which is in turn blocked.
In the case here, your java class is also single threaded and not reading the 'cat' output before reaching the blocking point filling the 'cat' input.
This problem  goes beyond trying to read a small N bytes in order to write N bytes, because:
a) you don't know if the ratio is 1:1, and you should not rely on that,
b) you have to also read the stderr of the process in case it is blocked writing to that stream.
In general, you end up starting 2 threads (I call them 'pumps') on stdout and stderr, while you main thread can write to stdin.
And yet, this is not the end. You will likely have to read after the child process is ended, until end of file (EOF) unless you don't care about those bytes. If the main thread terminates the process on purpose, it may want to interrupt these 'pumps' if you don't want them to continue reading until the EOF of stdout/stderr stream. Otherwise, you need some extra care (waiting for both pumps to have finished).
